# Using Youtube IFrame API from closure script

Tags: google-closure, youtube-iframe-api

What is the correct way to initialize Youtube IFrame player API in the closure script?

Right now I have following part in the soy template:

```
<iframe id="youtube-player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Closure script contains following part:

```
var player;
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    console.log('api ready');
    player = new YT.Player('youtube-player', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
};
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    console.log('player ready');
    event.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
}
```

First I was struggling on getting `YT.Player` constructor to work, but then I added extern from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/closure-compiler/master/contrib/externs/google_youtube_iframe.js to the closure compiler and `player` object was created successfully.

However I am getting `api ready` message in the console but not `player ready` which means `onPlayerReady` is never called.

When I'm trying to create iframe by passing id of empty `div` and adding `videoId` parameter to `YT.Player` constructor options - youtube iframe is created but not pointing to any video.

Also I tried to add `onPlayerReady` function to externs but it did not helped as well.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `events` field in the `YT.Player` constructor options was renamed by closure compiler.

So the correct way to execute it to avoid renaming is:

```
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    console.log('api ready');
    player = new YT.Player(playerId, {
        'events': {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
    console.log(player);
};
```